# PostgreSQL combining a count, a last 7 days count and a last 30 days count Grouped by days

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count, date-arithmetic

I have a small table (`TABLEA`) which has two columns `IDA` & `DATETIMEA`.

**TABLEA**

```
IDA  DATETIMEA
1    2020-03-16 13:15:00
2    2020-03-17 15:25:00
3    2020-03-18 17:10:00
5    2020-03-19 11:44:00
5    2020-03-20 12:55:00
5    2020-03-21 19:35:00
7    2020-03-22 10:13:00
8    2020-03-22 15:25:00
8    2020-03-28 12:12:00
9    2020-03-29 17:55:00
10   2020-03-30 11:54:00
12   2020-03-30 15:35:00
12   2020-03-31 13:19:00
```

I am trying to get the total `IDA`'s per day, Total in Last 7 days and total in last 30 days.

**Expected Output**

```
DATE       DAY L7 L30
2020-03-16 1   1  1
2020-03-17 1   2  2
2020-03-18 1   3  3
2020-03-19 1   4  4
2020-03-20 1   5  5
2020-03-21 1   6  6
2020-03-22 2   8  8  
2020-03-28 1   3  9
2020-03-29 1   4  10
2020-03-30 2   6  12
2020-03-31 1   7  13
```

I have tried putting the date related outputs in sub queries but they return 0.

```
SELECT t.DATETIMEA::date date,
COUNT(t.*) "day",
(SELECT COUNT(w.*) FROM TABLEA w WHERE w.DATETIMEA::date BETWEEN w.DATETIMEA::date AND w.DATETIMEA::date - 7) week,
(SELECT COUNT(m.*) FROM TABLEA m WHERE m.DATETIMEA::date BETWEEN m.DATETIMEA::date AND m.DATETIMEA::date - 30) "month"
FROM TABLEA t
GROUP BY t.DATETIMEA::date
ORDER BY t.DATETIMEA::date
```

Comment: Is `12` really repeated or is that a typo?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes to show the IDA's are not unique

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your data may have gaps in days, then you need a `range` frame specification rather than a `rows` frame. Happily Postgres supports this specification, so you can do:

```
select
    datetimea::date date,
    count(*) "day",
    sum(count(*)) over(
        order by datetimea::date
        range between '7 day' preceding and current row
    ) l7,
        sum(count(*)) over(
        order by datetimea::date
        range between '30 day' preceding and current row
    ) l30
from mytable
group by datetimea::date
order by datetimea::date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=28fc67e5c816071a5cd3b2bfc53c458d)**:

```
date       | day | l7 | l30
:--------- | --: | -: | --:
2020-03-16 |   1 |  1 |   1
2020-03-17 |   1 |  2 |   2
2020-03-18 |   1 |  3 |   3
2020-03-19 |   1 |  4 |   4
2020-03-20 |   1 |  5 |   5
2020-03-21 |   1 |  6 |   6
2020-03-22 |   2 |  8 |   8
2020-03-28 |   1 |  4 |   9
2020-03-29 |   1 |  4 |  10
2020-03-30 |   2 |  4 |  12
2020-03-31 |   1 |  5 |  13
```

Comment: Day works but l7 and l30 have huge numbers, for example 2020-03-16 day: 1 L7 and L30 = 0.76e2

Comment: @Matt: this does work for your sample data in the fiddle though (I assume the differences in `l7` are due to typos on your end). How can you tel that the results are wrong?

Comment: My data is just a larger version of the sample data, and i can tell there wrong because no total should be 0.76e2

Comment: @Matt: maybe you want `count(distinct ida)` instead of `count(*)` (replace all three occurences of `count(*)`)? Without seeing sample data that demonstrates the issue, I can only guess.

Comment: Actually GMB, i just recreated mine on dbfiddle and it works, where as on elephantsql.com it is getting the incorrect values

Answer (score 2):

I think window functions do what you want:

```
select t.datetimea::date, count(*) as on_day,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by t.datetimea::date rows between 6 preceding and current row) as sum_7,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by t.datetimea::date rows between 29 preceding and current row) as sum_30
from tablea t
group by t.datetimea::date;
```

By "last 7 days", I assume you mean today and the preceding 6 days.  If you mean 7 days before today, the window frame can easily be adjusted.

Comment: Day works but l7 and l30 have huge numbers, for example 2020-03-16 day: 1 L7 and L30 = 0.76e2